# Burr XII distribution with location parameter

Tags: r

I'm trying to sample the R distribution with known parameters in R. 
I have parameters location, beta, alpha1 and alpha2 used in another software.
How can I generates samples in R?

I've been trying to use the function actuar::rburr(shape1, shape2, scale). Here shape1, shape2 and scale seem to match the known parameters beta, alpha1, alpha2. How can I introduce the location parameter? Is there an alternative parametrisation available in R?

The MPS package seems to internally use Burr XII with a location parameter, but only it is not exposed outside the package.

I realize this question is borderline of maths and software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the c.d.f. of the Burr XII distribution with location parameter can be written as

[image]

where mu is the location parameter, and given the function in `actuar`, I believe we may simply define

```
rburrl <- function(n, shape1, shape2, rate = 1, scale = 1/rate, location = 0)
  rburr(n, shape1, shape2, rate = 1, scale = 1/rate) + location
```

That is, we simply shift all the values sampled in the usual way by `location`.

Then, e.g.,

```
rburrl(5, 1, 1, location = 100)
# [1] 100.5653 103.1667 101.9258 108.8506 102.8404
```